# JS для данных, полученных AJAX'ом.

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, upload, mysql

При прокрутке страницы новые данные подгружаются AJAX'ом, но на полученные таким путём данные не распространяется действие JS и jQuery, определённых в основном файле. То есть, скажем, чтобы у полученной записи работала кнопка комментирования, нужно вместе с этой записью доставать и код. Так как-то:

```
$q=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news");
while($r=$q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo $r[text].'<div class="comment" id="'.$r[id].'">Comment</div><div id="comarea'.$r[id].'"></div>';
}

$('.comment').click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr(id);
$('#comarea'+id).html('<input>');
});

if(time_to_load===true){
jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',url:'load.php',success:function(html){$('#loaded').html(html);}});
}
```

Load.php

```
$q=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news");
while($r=$q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo $r[text].'<div class="comment" onclick="comment($r[id])"></div><div id="comarea'.$r[id].'"></div>';
}
<script>function comment(id){// вставить input}</script>
```

Есть ли другой способ обеспечивать джаваскриптом подгружаемые AJAX'ом данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть способ. http://api.jquery.com/on/
Допустим

```
$(document).on('click', '.comment', function(){
    alert('Он нажал на меня, хотя я подгрузился через ж');
})
```